# Get result of select output in proper order

Tags: mysql

I have the following mysql statement

```
SELECT login, personal_email 
FROM users 
WHERE personal_email in ('cc', 'bb', 'dd', 'aa')
```

I want the output in the following order.

```
+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| login                               | personal_email                |
+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
   xx                                     cc
   yy                                     bb
   zz                                     dd
   ll                                     aa
```

But I am getting output in random order, like below.

```
+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| login                               | personal_email                |
+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------
   ll                                     aa
   zz                                     dd
   xx                                     cc
   yy                                     bb
```

How do I get the results in proper order.

Comment: Use an `ORDER BY personal_email` clause at the end of your `select` statement.

Comment: If it is based on the order inside `in`, then its not possible.

Comment: Well, the order suggested by OP seems to be simply alphabetical ...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean alphabetical. Will edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

If it is alphabetical order that you want, you might want to have a look at `ORDER BY` clause. It will sort your results according to the alphabetical (or reverse alphabetical, depending on `ASC` or `DSC/DESC`).

Try this

```
ORDER BY personal_email
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort alphabetical using `order by` clause. Try below query:

```
select login, personal_email
from users
where personal_email in ('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd')
order by login
```

Comment: Sorry, edited the question. I don't want in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `order by` command. This takes one argument, `ASC` or `DESC` for ascending or descending order. Ascending order is A-Z / 1-9, descending order is Z-A / 9-1 etc. The default is `asc` - that is, if neither `asc` or `desc` appears after the order by, it defaults to `asc`

`SELECT a,b FROM foo ORDER BY a`